# How to post exception of arithmetic overflow in C/C++ with compiler convenience

Tags: android, c++, c, android-source

When I run Android program, I find a Native Exception, I believe this exception comes from a line of code which may cause arithmetic overflow. But the question is arithmetic overflow would not be report normally in C/C++, as least it is so when I test it with g++ and Linux OS.

I presume overflow would be reported because of some additional compiler functions when compiling Android. The exact my question is how to make the following code post some exceptions when running it.

```
int main(){
    size_t size = 0;
    size--;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is that overflow? The behaviour of unsigned integers in C is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

`size_t` is an unsigned type. There is never arithmetic overflow. Instead the result of all calculations on unsigned types are wrapped within the value range, as if by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value. This means that after `size--`, `size` will hold the value `SIZE_MAX`.

*Signed integer* overflow, on the other hand, has undefined behaviour. You might be interested in catching that. GCC has support for catching undefined behaviour related to signed integer overflow. Given the following program, undefined behaviour happens when `size = INT_MIN` is decremented:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
volatile int size = INT_MIN;
int main(){
    size--;
    printf("%d\n", size);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the program with

```
% gcc foo.c -Wall -Wextra -Woverflow -fsanitize=undefined
```

and no error occurs. If you run it, you will see

```
% ./a.out                                                
foo.c:5:9: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 - 1 
cannot be represented in type 'int'
2147483647
```

It is also possible to configure this to abort on first trouble, but I don't think it is as useful.

Comment: It does not work in the OP case,  as it does not detect wraparounds.